# best way to express urgency status

Tags: word-choice, grammar

If I want to express that I'm in urgent state what is the best way to say it?
like `I'm in haste! let me enter first please.`

Update:
I want a word used for general purposes: like a child is late for his school, or employee is late for his work.

ex `It's your work time! you must be in (some word)` .

Comment: Could you explain why "in a hurry" does not suit your purposes?

Comment: I recommend answering your own question if you already know the answer.  Your example could easily end with a reason unrelated to haste, as in, "You must not have a sense of urgency since you're always late." More context, please.

Comment: @user2407522 Alas, I don't have a good reference to back it up. If anyone else has one, they should feel free to submit it as an answer in my place.

Comment: I recommend a delete. It is off topic here since hurry is a plain synonym of haste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your work time! you must be in a hurry/ bustle/rush/ feverish haste. It's your work time! you must be running full pelt/ headlong/like mad/ at breakneck speed/hurry-scurry/ as if your life's depending on this. There are others idioms and words, too which I've forgotten by now

Comment: However, there's a universal way to express that you are hard-pressed and in an urgent situation which is to say: I'm fucked

Comment: I don't ask for something to describe that I am hard-pressed that much, see the update please.

Comment: It's your work time! you must be in a hurry/ bustle/rush/ feverish haste. It's your work time! you must be running full pelt/ headlong/like mad/head over heels/ at breakneck speed/hurry-scurry/ as if your life depending on this. There are others idioms and words, too.